# How to configure Jenkins to build a .net framework project when it depends on another .net project ?

Tags: asp.net, jenkins, msbuild, continuous-integration, jenkins-pipeline

I have a project that depends on another project, how can I configure Jenkins to use the reference of that project in the workspace.

For an example, project B depends on a certain set of classes from project A. Jenkins should be aware to build project A first and then B.

The trigger point is when a commit is pushed to the master of project B.

Comment: Are they part of the same solution? Or are you using NuGet? how does the build work locally?

Comment: No it not part of the same solution. To entirely different project. But referenced.

Comment: How are they referenced? absolute dll paths, GAC, project references etc.?

Comment: @MartinUllrich it was a project base reference I found a solution. Posted it as an answer. Would love your input on that.

Answer (score 0):

If a project depends upon another project, it is typically part of the same solution and always part of the same source tree.  This means the slave will probably have the source already - or if it doesn't, the step that obtains the source needs the workspace mapping updated to not exclude it.

Also, when a project depends upon another project, the reference information includes the path to the referenced project.  In the absence of solution file, this is used directly to build the other project with the same configuration (as in Debug/Release).

It's usually best to use a solution file instead of building projects directly as that ensures platform/configuration customisation is honoured as well as determining the correct build order of the projects.

Answer (score 0):

So I got it sorted out. Since my project was based on project reference, the path had to be the same.

Naming the Jenkins project folder same as the dependent project name I referenced solved the issue.

I was under the impression that another workspace can't access another workspace. But it seems to be Jenkins handles it internally when building projects.